# Bug scrolling on bitmapfill with big containers. Flex 3.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have the following scenario:

I create an HBox with a width of 1000000px (one million pixels of width).

this big HBox is contained inside another small HBox that has a width of 1000 px

```
<mx:HBox id="small" width="1000" >
   <mx:HBox id="big" width="1000000" />     
</mx:HBox>
```

Inside this big HBox I create a bitmapFill of a simple image, its just a pattern of lines

the problem is that the scrollBar of the small hbox doesnt work well, it just stops halfway, the thumb of the scrollbar keeps going, but the scrolling stops and the end of the big hbox is not beign reached.

Somebody knows a workaround for this? Thanks in advance. Here is the part of the code that makes the bitmapfill:

```
var shape:Shape = new Shape();
shape.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x008800);
shape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100, 100);

var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(0, 100, true, 0x00000000);
bd.draw(shape);

small.graphics.clear();
small.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData);             
small.graphics.drawRect(0,0,width, 400);
small.graphics.endFill();
```

Comment: Why do you have *anything* at a million pixels?!? Also, there are [limitations on the Flash Player](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/496/cpsid_49662.html).

Comment: its something like a custom history chart, this will have the history of certain events and the display will show A LOT of years in data

Comment: Having a lot of data *doesn't* mean you need to render it all at the same time.  Why would you render something that the user can't see?

Comment: Also, if you're using Flex, why not use the charts that are already available there, or use a 3rd party one that's online?

Comment: you are right, its just that the component have already been created and I need to fix this, and I thought if there could be an easy workaround for this. Because it is a custom component, I would need to program all the logic to "hide" the unseen information, and that would consume me a lot of time. But well, I just want to know if there is a posible solution for this.

Comment: Sorry, there isn't.  Custom component or not, I've never seen *anything* be drawn that isn't viewable by the user for performance reasons.  You need to rethink/redo your component or just use what's readily available.

Comment: No, even if it was possible (which it isn't) I agree with Jax - this is a bad idea.  Do you have an idea how much memory a 1 million x 1 million bitmap would consume, let alone processing? 10 quadrillion pixels if it were possible?  :)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has told me, the approach I'm trying to develop is not possible and is really not recommended. But as adobe has point out, flash 11 will remove the size limits, so, if you want to do something like the big bitmap I wanted to create, then you will have to wait for **flash 11**